# Unreachable host inside network

Tags: networking, configuration, netmask

I'm trying to use some unusual network configurations.

Host1 (internet gateway): IP: 192.168.0.1 Mask: 255.255.0.0

Host2: IP: 192.168.1.10 Mask: 255.255.0.0 Default gateway: 192.168.0.1

I can't ping the Host1 from Host2. Did I miss something here?

I'm using Linux Ubuntu 10.04 and the gateway is a internet router.
I've tested the same scenario in another place, with every hardware different from those, and got the same results.
Tested in an embedded system (linux) too, same results.

Thanks very much.

Comment: Some more info would be useful; what's the OS of the two hosts? Might either host be using any software that might block ICMP? Can you ping in the other direction (pinging host2 from host1)?

Comment: Try setting your masks to 255.255.254.0, which should cover just the two class-c blocks you are using.

Comment: What are the devices?  I would not be at all surprised if a cheap consumer router simply can't handle a subnet bigger than a class C.

Comment: masks 255.255.254.0 didn't work. Changed in both hosts (pc and router).

Answer (score 2):

*Did I miss something here?*

Cable plugged in? Servers switched on? OS installed? :-)

No where near enough details to help sorry. What OS are you running, can you supply the output of the networking config tools (ipconfig/ifconfig/etc). Are the link-lights lit up on your NICs? Are you using a switch or crossover? etc etc etc.

Comment: Everything set.
Changing the ip and mask of Hos2 to 192.168.0.10, 255.255.255.0, it works fine.
Running Linux Ubuntu 10.04 (tested on embedded linux too... same behavior).

Answer (score 0):

Didn't answer: Are both on the same switch/How are they physically connected?

If so, what about software firewalls?

For reference: Your network is CIDR: 192.168.0.0/16.  This encompasses: 192.168.0.0-192.168.255.255... sounds theoretical... do your hosts support CIDR subnetting?

Use the IETF standard range for private Class B subnets: 172.16.0.0/255.255.0.0 (at least to test).

See:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_IPv4_address_spaces
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4_subnetting_reference
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classful_network

Comment: Looks like my Switch was doing something wrong.
I'll try some more tests and will be back when I get results.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sure, i mean... that would definitely do it... just think... Ping is "sort of an application," meaning, one computer has to be able to have something living somewhere that says "oh, hey... check out this ICMP echo request... I guess I should response with an ICMP echo reply."  This means, it has to traverse up the stack until it's serviced... so switches, software firewall, etc, should all be considered; just like dealing with inter-application networking.